# iPython: How to get 3 variables from user

Tags: python, interface, widget

I've got a problem. I have to write program, that check what was day of the week of given DAY, MONTH, YEAR.

I defined a function 'dayoftheweek' which finds day of the week of given date.
But here is my problem. I don't know how to get three variables d,m,y from user with GUI.
Also I don't know how to make a fine button saying "Accept" and will move my 3 variables into dayoftheweek function.

Here is the code

```
    import math
from tkinter import *

def dayoftheweek(d, m, y):
    a=math.floor((14-m)/12)
    y1=r+4800-a
    n=m+12*-3
    l=d+math.floor((153*n)/5)+365*y1+math.floor(y1/4)-math.floor(y1/100)+math.floor(y1/100)-32045
    p = (l%7)+1
    return p


def date():
   d = int(e1.get())
   m = int(e2.get())
   y = int(e3.get())
   print(dayoftheweek(d, m, y))


master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Day").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Month").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Year").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)



mainloop( )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print something in Tkinter, you can't just use `print` statement in your code.

You have to have a Label somewhere, and then change the contents of that Label. To do that you have to have a StringVar assigned to that Label. A StringVar is like a special case of normal strings, special because everytime it changes it will refresh how your window looks. That's what I did here:

```
printVar = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=printVar).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Just added a Label in which we can update some text, aka "print to".

Additionally I added a Button, so that you could call your function `date`. You can make the window do something by using buttons that call assigned commands, or by binding keys (i.e. Enter, Space...) to the window.

```
button = Button(master, text="Ok", command=date).grid(row=3, column=1))
```

Now everytime you press your button the function `date` will be called, and the content of printVar will be changed and displayed in the Label.

Here's the full code, I also added the `r=100` because your code is incomplete and gives the error that `global r is not defined`.

```
import math
from Tkinter import *

def dayoftheweek(d, m, y):
    r = 100 

    a=math.floor((14-m)/12)
    y1=r+4800-a
    n=m+12*-3
    l=d+math.floor((153*n)/5)+365*y1+math.floor(y1/4)-math.floor(y1/100)+math.floor(y1/100)-32045
    p = (l%7)+1
    return p


def date():
   d = int(e1.get())
   m = int(e2.get())
   y = int(e3.get())
   printVar.set(dayoftheweek(d, m, y))


master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Day").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(master, text="Month").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(master, text="Year").grid(row=2, column=0)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

printVar = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=printVar).grid(row=4, column=1)

button = Button(master, text="Ok", command=date).grid(row=3, column=1)



mainloop( )
```